# Possible to remove the rectangular shadow from a curve image?

Tags: css, svg

I have created a svg shape. I need to remove the rectangular shadow. Is it possible to keep the shape without the rectangular shadow. You see the shadow by inspect this element. Here below the screenshot that I need your help.
[image]

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #0097d1;
}
.inner-bg {
  width: 225px;
  height: 252px;
  position: relative;
  left: 150px;
}
.inner-bg2 {
  height: 413px;
  width: 354px;
}
.photo_rectangle_inverse {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#shape);
  clip-path: url(#shape);
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(1px)
}
.hover-bg {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s ease;
}
.inner-bg:hover .hover-bg,
.inner-bg2:hover .hover-bg {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="shape">
      <path d="M1397.715,175.794c-25.751-15.171-69.059-38.065-129.139-60.976c-67.575-25.768-142.155-46.303-221.671-61.035 C947.395,35.348,839.829,26,727.195,26C262.767,26,66.548,171.319,29.886,202.439c-2.296,27.868-7.736,113.978,0.68,229.038 C36.582,513.729,48.399,594.485,65.69,671.5c21.543,95.959,51.69,186.337,89.604,268.625 c34.129,74.072,64.323,133.951,95.024,188.442c36.672,65.09,75.123,124.286,117.55,180.97 c47.205,63.067,99.354,123.173,159.428,183.753c60.364,60.873,127.474,120.997,204.717,183.385
 c76.575-61.797,143.891-122.42,205.319-184.881c60.193-61.205,112.963-122.409,161.323-187.11
 c42.74-57.182,81.631-116.64,118.893-181.771c30.475-53.269,60.348-111.148,94.01-182.15
 c39.049-82.368,69.602-173.132,90.807-269.769c17.023-77.58,28.095-159.092,32.906-242.272
 c6.667-115.242-0.692-202.073-3.775-231.25C1424.622,192.59,1413.379,185.023,1397.715,175.794z" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>

<svg class="inner-bg" viewBox="0 0 1464 1710">
  <g>
    <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M1401.85,170.106c-25.92-15.308-69.51-38.408-129.982-61.524c-68.004-25.994-143.056-46.708-223.071-61.567
 C948.692,28.426,840.49,19,727.195,19c-119.749,0-231.57,9.722-332.358,28.895c-80.505,15.314-154.182,36.658-218.984,63.438
c-57.568,23.79-97.325,47.554-120.54,63.301c-16.03,10.873-26.588,19.521-32.163,24.386c-2.144,24.728-8.309,113.118,0.409,232.628
 c6.028,82.638,17.889,163.781,35.253,241.177c21.654,96.517,51.976,187.435,90.123,270.228
 c34.21,74.249,64.487,134.289,95.284,188.949c36.822,65.356,75.435,124.801,118.044,181.729
 c47.401,63.329,99.757,123.675,160.061,184.487c61.688,62.207,130.392,123.63,209.686,187.446
 c78.608-63.193,147.521-125.116,210.313-188.963c60.417-61.433,113.388-122.871,161.939-187.827
 c42.913-57.413,81.956-117.104,119.361-182.485c30.566-53.428,60.518-111.46,94.259-182.629
c39.306-82.907,70.045-174.247,91.366-271.482c17.1-77.986,28.213-159.913,33.03-243.505c6.913-119.938-1.295-209.211-4.161-235.164
 C1431.553,188.84,1419.487,180.523,1401.85,170.106z" />
  </g>
  <image xlink:href='http://lorempixel.com/225/262' class='photo_rectangle_inverse' width="1464px" height="1710px" />
  <path class="hover-bg" fill="#0097d1" fill-opacity=".6" d="M1401.85,170.106c-25.92-15.308-69.51-38.408-129.982-61.524c-68.004-25.994-143.056-46.708-223.071-61.567
 C948.692,28.426,840.49,19,727.195,19c-119.749,0-231.57,9.722-332.358,28.895c-80.505,15.314-154.182,36.658-218.984,63.438
c-57.568,23.79-97.325,47.554-120.54,63.301c-16.03,10.873-26.588,19.521-32.163,24.386c-2.144,24.728-8.309,113.118,0.409,232.628
 c6.028,82.638,17.889,163.781,35.253,241.177c21.654,96.517,51.976,187.435,90.123,270.228
 c34.21,74.249,64.487,134.289,95.284,188.949c36.822,65.356,75.435,124.801,118.044,181.729
 c47.401,63.329,99.757,123.675,160.061,184.487c61.688,62.207,130.392,123.63,209.686,187.446
 c78.608-63.193,147.521-125.116,210.313-188.963c60.417-61.433,113.388-122.871,161.939-187.827
 c42.913-57.413,81.956-117.104,119.361-182.485c30.566-53.428,60.518-111.46,94.259-182.629
c39.306-82.907,70.045-174.247,91.366-271.482c17.1-77.986,28.213-159.913,33.03-243.505c6.913-119.938-1.295-209.211-4.161-235.164
 C1431.553,188.84,1419.487,180.523,1401.85,170.106z" />
</svg>


<svg class="inner-bg2" viewBox="0 0 1464 1710">
  <g>
    <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M1401.85,170.106c-25.92-15.308-69.51-38.408-129.982-61.524c-68.004-25.994-143.056-46.708-223.071-61.567
 C948.692,28.426,840.49,19,727.195,19c-119.749,0-231.57,9.722-332.358,28.895c-80.505,15.314-154.182,36.658-218.984,63.438
c-57.568,23.79-97.325,47.554-120.54,63.301c-16.03,10.873-26.588,19.521-32.163,24.386c-2.144,24.728-8.309,113.118,0.409,232.628
 c6.028,82.638,17.889,163.781,35.253,241.177c21.654,96.517,51.976,187.435,90.123,270.228
 c34.21,74.249,64.487,134.289,95.284,188.949c36.822,65.356,75.435,124.801,118.044,181.729
 c47.401,63.329,99.757,123.675,160.061,184.487c61.688,62.207,130.392,123.63,209.686,187.446
 c78.608-63.193,147.521-125.116,210.313-188.963c60.417-61.433,113.388-122.871,161.939-187.827
 c42.913-57.413,81.956-117.104,119.361-182.485c30.566-53.428,60.518-111.46,94.259-182.629
c39.306-82.907,70.045-174.247,91.366-271.482c17.1-77.986,28.213-159.913,33.03-243.505c6.913-119.938-1.295-209.211-4.161-235.164
 C1431.553,188.84,1419.487,180.523,1401.85,170.106z" />
  </g>
  <image xlink:href='http://lorempixel.com/1464/1710' class='photo_rectangle_inverse' width="1464px" height="1710px" />
  <path class="hover-bg" fill="#0097d1" fill-opacity=".6" d="M1401.85,170.106c-25.92-15.308-69.51-38.408-129.982-61.524c-68.004-25.994-143.056-46.708-223.071-61.567
 C948.692,28.426,840.49,19,727.195,19c-119.749,0-231.57,9.722-332.358,28.895c-80.505,15.314-154.182,36.658-218.984,63.438
c-57.568,23.79-97.325,47.554-120.54,63.301c-16.03,10.873-26.588,19.521-32.163,24.386c-2.144,24.728-8.309,113.118,0.409,232.628
 c6.028,82.638,17.889,163.781,35.253,241.177c21.654,96.517,51.976,187.435,90.123,270.228
 c34.21,74.249,64.487,134.289,95.284,188.949c36.822,65.356,75.435,124.801,118.044,181.729
 c47.401,63.329,99.757,123.675,160.061,184.487c61.688,62.207,130.392,123.63,209.686,187.446
 c78.608-63.193,147.521-125.116,210.313-188.963c60.417-61.433,113.388-122.871,161.939-187.827
 c42.913-57.413,81.956-117.104,119.361-182.485c30.566-53.428,60.518-111.46,94.259-182.629
c39.306-82.907,70.045-174.247,91.366-271.482c17.1-77.986,28.213-159.913,33.03-243.505c6.913-119.938-1.295-209.211-4.161-235.164
 C1431.553,188.84,1419.487,180.523,1401.85,170.106z" />
</svg>
```

Please check also the [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ls0s5z51/3/)

Comment: Sorry, you mean the rectangular area that you _only_ see when using the developer tools? Why is that a problem?

Comment: Wait a minute, are you talking about the focus effect? You mean that you want the graphic to be highlighted when the mouse is over the visible area of the picture only, rather than the whole rectangular area?

Comment: @Lister you right. I only want the curved shape not whole the rectangular area when I hover over. See the screenshot: http://prntscr.com/9d7uxu When you hover over small shape and place your mouse below the small one (big one) that I marked with an arrow, only the small shape is selected not the big shape. Hope you understand now.

Comment: @RonySatiar the small image should not be selectable at all? Its unclear what you want.

Comment: @RobertLongson I think my point was not clear to you. Please see this http://prntscr.com/9d88m1 I have marked with a rectangular area and placed an arrow. I want to hover the big image when I place my cursor where the arrow in now located. Hope it's now clear to you.

Comment: @RonySatiar you'd have to make a single `<svg>` that displayed both things.

Comment: take a look at this.. http://sarasoueidan.com/blog/css-shapes/#example-3